# How do I limit the dates a user can choose in CakePHP FormHelper's date field?

Tags: php, date, cakephp, formhelper

I'd like to limit user choices for a date to Mondays only.

I store the date field in a MySQL database, and CakePHP automagically generates a date picker for me on the add/edit forms when I use `echo $this->Form->input('date');`. But it generates drop down menus for year, month and day. That does not seem like a good way to limit user choices to four or five days a month.

I've looked through the [options available for the datetime input field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#datetime-options) on the CakePHP site, and `interval` is exactly like what I need, but it only applies to the minutes box on a datetime field, and appears to have no effect on the date field.

Is there a clean CakePHP way to go about this, or do I just generate the list of dates on my own and create a drop-down box with those values?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use jquery datepicker.. You can also limit the date on datepicker

Comment: That's a good alternative option. I guess there's no clean way to get Cake to do this?

Comment: You might be able. but it will cost you lots of time. very less change to achieve what you what you are expecting - I think the best option is datepicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a nice UI use Jquery DatePicker

```
//Cake view
    echo $this->Form->input('created', array('type'=>'text', 'id'=>'created'));

//Jquery 
    $('#created').datepicker({
         dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
```

Otherwise you can restrict the date input

```
//Year
echo $this->Form->year('purchased-year', 2000, date('Y'));
//Month
echo $this->Form->month('mob');
//Day
echo $this->Form->day('created');

FormHelper::hour(string $fieldName, boolean $format24Hours, array $attributes)
Creates a select element populated with the hours of the day.

FormHelper::minute(string $fieldName, array $attributes)
Creates a select element populated with the minutes of the hour.

FormHelper::meridian(string $fieldName, array $attributes)
Creates a select element populated with ‘am’ and ‘pm’.
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-date-and-time-inputs

Comment: Thanks, got it working! Definitely the cleanest solution I've seen.